# How do I send the terminal a bell through vim/nvim programmatically?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to add the terminal bell (`echo "\a"`) to a plugin, to for example get alerted when a build finishes. But I can't figure out how. I've tried `:!echo -e "\a"` and `:!echo system("echo -e \"a\"")`

Comment: You mean you don't hear it? the command looks correct.

Comment: oh.. I actually do hear it, but only in vim. was previously testing this inside neovim. but, is there a solution that works in both?

Comment: If neovim backported it, then you should probably use Vim's `:help sound_playevent()` or `:help sound_playfile()`.